# Error: Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

Alguém pode me ajudar com isto?

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@hospitalId".
```

**PendenciaController:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    if (!Cookies.Exists("hid"))
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new { area = "Entrar" });

    var hospitalId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("hid"));
    var lista = await Dia1Service.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
    return View(lista);
}
```

**Dia1Service:**

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Dia1>> GetPendenciasByUser(int hospitalId)
            {
                return await _dia1Repository.GetPendenciasByUser(hospitalId);
            }

**Dia1Repository:**

public async Task<IEnumerable<Dia1>> GetPendenciasByUser(int hospitalId)
        {
            const string query = @"SELECT d1.PatientId AS Id,
                                   c.inpac AS Iniciais,
                                   CASE 
                                    WHEN (CONVERT(DATE,r.RandomizacaoData , 103) = CONVERT(DATE,d1.dtd1 , 103)) OR d1.dtd1 IS NULL
                                        THEN r.RandomizacaoData
                                    WHEN (CONVERT(DATE,r.RandomizacaoData , 103) < CONVERT(DATE,d1.dtd1 , 103)) 
                                        THEN CONVERT(datetime,d1.dtd1 , 103)
                                    ELSE r.RandomizacaoData
                                   END DataRandomizacao
                            FROM Basics_Dia1 d1
                            LEFT JOIN Basics_Cadastro c ON c.PatientId = d1.PatientId AND d1.StatPree = 1
                            LEFT JOIN basics_Randomizacao r ON r.PatientId = c.PatientId AND r.CentroId = c.HospitalId
                            WHERE c.HospitalId = @hospitalId AND c.StatPree = 1 AND c.Removido = 0";

            var cn = Db.Database.Connection;
            var lista = await cn.QueryAsync<Dia1>(query, new { Hospital = hospitalId });

            return lista;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicação

O valor da propriedade `Hospital` do objeto anônimo utilizado no parâmetro do comando não condiz com a especificada no `SQL`. Altere a linha de declaração da variável lista para a sugerida no exemplo abaixo:

## Exemplo

```
var lista = await cn.QueryAsync<Dia1>(query, new { HospitalId = hospitalId });
```

Comment: cara obrigado eu nem percebi, meus olhos estão viciados já

Comment: Acontece. Você precisa aceitar a resposta.